# When running tests with jest i get Test suite failed to run randomly

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs

When running tests with jest i get Test suite failed to run randomly
● Test suite failed to run

```
Error [ERR_VM_MODULE_NOT_MODULE]: Provided module is not an instance of Module.
```

Same test can work one time but second time i get error ERR_VM_MODULE_NOT_MODULE.

This is how i run test

`node --require=dotenv/config --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --config ./jest.config.json`

my jest version "28.1.3"